# At what score do you stop receiving points for upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, community-wiki, up-votes

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv/11834872#11834872) and currently have 39 upvotes. I just noticed I no longer receive the +10 for each upvote.

[image]

**QUESTION:**
At what score do you stop receiving points for upvotes?

Comment: a) Community wiki, b) reputation cap at 200 in one day from votes. That one looks like CW.

Comment: The lesson here: try to make fewer more substantial edits, rather than lots of little edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the point it becomes a Community Wiki (from being edited 10 times):

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that!